# Can I exclude "More" Button in UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to make UIActivityViewController with SMS, Mail, Facebook and Twitter buttons.
I Know about property "excludedActivityTypes", but I can't find information about excluding "More" button. My code:

```
ActivityItemProvider *activityProvider = [[ActivityItemProvider alloc] init];

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[activityProvider]
                                                                         applicationActivities:@[]];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:true completion:nil];
```

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so because the `more button`is the new standard in `IOS 8` for `UIActivityViewController`.

Comment: If I'll find information about this, my post will be updated. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is the button where the user choose to enable app extensions, and you are not allowed to hide extension .